# Getting somthing to save to a non specified desktop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making an advanced web browser that has an option to save your current page as a .html file, how do I get this to save to the desktop, but not MY desktop, any desktop in general

```
Private Sub SavePagesHTMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SavePagesHTMLToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim browser As webbrowserfunctions = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    Dim filename As String = InputBox("This will save the code of this webpage to your desktop", "Save HTML", "insertdesirednamehere.html")
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & filename

    Try
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            Dim alltext As String
            alltext = browser.DocumentText
            File.WriteAllText(path, alltext)
        Else
            File.Create(path).Dispose()
            Dim alltext As String
            alltext = browser.DocumentText
            File.WriteAllText(path, alltext)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use [SaveFileDialog Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Fabio That's not exactly what I meant, The saving works fine I just don't know how to get it to save to the desktop eg. "c:/Users/yoshi/desktop", if I give this app to someone else, this save wont work because their user is different to mine

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` is resolved when it is called, so it automatically gets set to the user's desktop. Incidentally, you should use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to concatenate directory names and file names.

Answer (score 0):

Use `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop` command as a location.

If the program will run on other machine, the username, in your case *yoshi* (I assume this is your question) will change accordingly.